# Concept as a template argument in type-constraint

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

What would be the correct syntax in the following code snippet:

```
template <class T>
concept engine = requires(T&& t) {
  { t.start() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};

template <class T>
concept car = requires(T&& t) {
 { t.get_engine() } -> std::convertible_to<std::optional<engine>>; // this would not compile!
};
```

Comment: The template that is going to use `car` is not going to call `t.get_engine` and get "something". It's going to get a specific type, one which will behave in a way that your template specifically expects. So at the point of use, you already have some idea what type `get_engine` returns. So `car` needs to be templated on the expected engine type.

Comment: What error are you getting?  This compiled fine for me on MSVC latest.  Please show your imports.

Comment: @OzSolomon I'm wondering if MSVC is a good example of a standard-conformant compiler :-).    [Here you can see](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i3cF5wgjSi8npBgI) what GCC says.

Answer (score 2):

How about using template lambda?

```
#include <optional>
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept engine = requires(T&& t) {
  { t.start() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};

template <class T>
concept car = requires(T&& t) {
  []<engine E>(const std::optional<E>&) { } (t.get_engine());
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3o88ozc56)

Comment: Thanks! Trying to parse the syntax: what does `(t.get_engine())` stand for here?

Comment: @IgorR. Immediately call the lambda with `()` and pass in `t.get_engine()`. Since the parameter type of lambda is `const std::optional<E>&`, the expression is valid only if `t.get_engine()` can bind `const std::optional<E>&` where `E` satisfies `engine`.